# Progress bar on button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, progress-bar

I need to add a progress bar above a button. When I click that button once I need to stop that progress bar after download completes.

I am new to objective C. Is this possible? Please give me some sample code or any reference.

Comment: Have you checked apple's UIProgressView reference ? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Just add a button to view and then add a preogressView to the view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use UIActivityIndicatorView

[Tutorial:](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/use-activityindicator-in-iphone/)

[Mobile Tuts Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiactivityindicatorview_mbprogresshud/)

Good Luck